# Getting user input in a loop based on a user-provided number of iterations

Tags: python-3.x

A organisation classifies the amounts donated by the public into two different tiers:

- Tier 1: Amounts greater than or equal to $100
- Tier 2: Amounts less than $100

Write a program that can ask for the total number of donations received, as well as the donated amounts. After which, display the following for each tier:

1. List of donated amounts
2. Total amount
3. Average amount

After the user has input the total number of donors, the `while` loop will print `"Enter amount donated by donor (number)"` until it reaches the last donor. I have no idea how to go about doing that. This is my current attempt:

```py
donors=int(input("Enter total number of donations received: "))
tier1=[]
tier2=[]
i=0
while donors < (donors+1):
    amount=int(input("Enter amount donated by donor {0}: ".format(i+1)))
    if amount >=100:
        tier1.append(amount)
    else:
        tier2.append(amount)
average1=(sum(tier1)/len(tier1))
average2=(sum(tier2)/len(tier2))
print("Tier 1 donations received is " +str(tier1))
print("Total amount for Tier 1 is {0}".format(sum(tier1)))
print("Average amount for Tier 1 is $" + str(average1))
print("Tier 1 donations received is " + str(tier2))
print("Total amount for Tier 1 is {0}".format(sum(tier2)))
print("Average amount for Tier 1 is $" + str(average2))
```

The output keeps printing `"Enter amount donated by donor 1:"` instead of

```
"Enter amount donated by donor 1: "
"Enter amount donated by donor 2: "
"Enter amount donated by donor 3: "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will run infinitely, since `donors < (donors + 1)` always evaluates to `True`. Perhaps you meant to say `while i < donors`, in order to loop from i=0 at the start to when `i == donors`, at which point it will stop. For this to work, you have to increment the value of `i` in your loop though:

```
i=0
while i < donors:
    i += 1  # Increment your counter here
    amount=int(input("Enter amount donated by donor {0}: ".format(i)))
    if amount >=100:
        tier1.append(amount)
    else:
        tier2.append(amount)
```

A better and more pythonic method is to use `range` and a `for` loop for this instead of `while`. Replace the following:

```
i=0
while donors < (donors+1):
```

With:

```
for i in range(donors):
```

Comment: Ah so for i in range needs to be used instead of while... have been grinding my gears around while and for loops without thinking of the range function... Thank you for the help!